# How can i insert a string into editText.setText()

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hello i have a question that is the one which i put in title.
I have this example that i extract from my code

```
String text = "Test";
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idField);
editText.setText(text);
```

And I can't convert int o charSequence
My objective is put a string into the editText.setText();

Here is my onCreate:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        fileExist();
        sessionTimeOut();
        passwordValidation(getLocalPassword());
    } catch (FileNotExistException e) {
        setLoginActivity();
    } catch (SessionTimeOutException e) {
        String text="Sometext";
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        setLoginActivity(R.string.sessionOut);
               editText.setText(text);


    } catch (PasswordInvalidException e) {
        setLoginActivity(R.string.criterios);
    }
    setWelcomeBackLayout();
}
```

The error is located where editText.setText(text); is located

There is my error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: pt.edu.es_loule, PID: 3498
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.edu.es_loule/pt.edu.es_loule.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at pt.edu.es_loule.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:46)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: No need to convert a `String` will work just fine. I think you have a typo-- "...convert int o charSequence" should be "...convert into charSequence"?? and "ediText"  should be "editText"

Comment: i forgot to put objective here @diegoveloper

Comment: Your question is a little unclear; try editing and giving a little more explanation on what exactly you want.

Comment: @Taslim i've just updated

Comment: I think `editText.setText(sometext);` where sometext is a String should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your layout xml file, you editText variable is null because your reference "idField" is incorrect.

Don't forget to call `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` before you get the reference of your view.

---

**UPDATE**

You forgot to call to `setContentView` method

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
  ...
```

Comment: It was just my mistake rewriting the example, i've updated ty for you attention xd

Comment: so, what is the problem? it should works fine, what error did you get?

Comment: what is the setWelcomeBackLayout method? maybe you could move that method to the first line

Answer (score 0):

String implements CharSequence so String.valueOf(aInt) does works as argument.

Comment: I think he had a typo-- "...convert int o charSequence"  should be "...convert into charSequence"